# Worin unterscheiden sich „über“ und „durch“?

Tags: preposition, meaning-in-context, grammar-identification

In einer Lückentextübung hätte ich in folgenden Sätzen *durch* eingetragen, doch *über* wird als korrekte Lösung angegeben.

Könnte mir bitte jemand erklären, warum *über* hier korrekt, und *durch* falsch ist?

1. Doch ________ unsere Sinne nehmen wir die Umwelt in uns auf.
2. Banken geben nicht gerne zu, dass es ein Sicherheitsrisiko im Onlinebanking gibt - den Computer des Kunden. __________ ihn können kriminelle Hacker Zugang zum Netzwerk der Bank, zu den Kunden, zum
   Geld erlangen.
3. Die Absa-Bank in Südafrika verhält sich anders - als ein Hacker
   __________ drei Kundencomputer von der Bank eindrang, gab die Bank den Einbruch zu und weigerte sich, die Kunden zu entschädigen.

Comment: Satz 3 wirkt insgesamt seltsam. "Drei Kundencomputer von der Bank" ist kein korrektes Deutsch (allenfalls Kleinkindsprache). Richtig wäre "drei Kundencomputer der Bank", oder eigentlich wohl am ehesten: "die Computer von drei Kunden der Bank" bzw. "die Computer dreier Bankkunden" oder "drei Computer von Kunden der Bank", oder was immer auch der konkrete Fall ist. -  Außerdem ist die logische Verbindung zwischen "Bank gibt Einbruch zu" und "Bank weigert sich zu zahlen" nicht ersichtlich. Ist vielleicht gemeint "Die Bank gab den Einbruch zu, weigerte sich **aber**, die Kunden zu entschädigen"?

Comment: Auch der zweite Satz erscheint mir ohne weiteren Kontext merkwürdig. Ist gemeint, dass die Hacker sich Zugang zu Computern von Bankkunden beschaffen? Aber sie brauchen doch nur die Zugangsdaten und können das von ihrem eigenen Computer aus erledigen. Welcher Hacker bricht denn zusätzlich noch ein? Oder ist gemeint, dass die Hacker eigene Kundenkonten eröffnen? Dann ist die gewählte Formulierung irreführend. Und das 'Zugang ... zu den Kunden, zum Geld erlangen' ist nebulös: Was soll sich dabei abspielen und wie geht das vonstatten?

Answer (score 2):

»[Über](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ueber_auf_darueber_darauf#Bedeutung9)« wird u. a. verwendet, wenn wie bei all deinen Beispielen ein Weg beschrieben wird, während »durch« bei kausalem Gebrauch eine Ursache benennt.

> Über unsere Sinne nehmen wir die Umwelt auf.
>   Über den Computer des Kunden dringen Hacker ins Banknetzwerk ein.
>
> Durch schludrige Sicherheitsmaßnahmen kann das passieren.
>   Er ist durch Krankheit geschwächt.

In vielen Fällen kann »über«, wenn Wegbeschreibung, auch mit »via« oder »mittels« ausgedrückt werden.

> Filme sind auch über das Internet zu vermarkten.
>   Filme sind auch via Internet zu vermarkten.
>
> Die Last wurde über einen Flaschenzug aufs Dach gehievt.
>   *(auf dem Weg eines Flaschenzuges)*
>   Die Last wurde mittels Flaschenzug aufs Dach gehievt.

Answer (score 1):

In allen drei Fällen sind beide Präpositionen denkbar, allerdings unterscheiden sich die jeweiligen Bedeutungen.

Im ersten Satz kann die Präposition 'durch' entweder ein mittelbares Agens (etwa wie ein Repeater in einem Netzwerk) bezeichnen. Vergleiche

> Ich habe durch einen Kollegen von der freien Stelle erfahren.

Das heißt: Der Kollege ist nicht die ursprüngliche Quelle der Nachricht.

Oder mit 'durch' könnte das Agens eines Satzes mit passivischem Nebensinn bezeichnet werden:

> Ich habe erst durch meine Freundin aus Blackpool richtig Englisch
>   gelernt.

Das heißt: Sie hat mir Englisch beigebracht. In der Praxis vermischen sich bei 'durch' diese beiden Bedeutungen.

Eine auf den ersten Blick naheliegende weitere Bedeutungsmöglichkeit, nämlich dass die Umwelt *durch* die Sinne *hindurch* in unser Bewusstsein 'hineinspaziert' wie bei einer *Durchgangstür*, halte ich für nicht sinnentsprechend.

Hingegen würde 'über' würde den Weg bezeichnen. Es kommt also bei Satz 1 darauf an, ob ich sagen will, dass die Sinne der **Weg der Umweltverarbeitung** (= über) oder dass sie eine erste **Instanz der Umweltverarbeitung** (= durch) sind.

Für Satz 2 und Satz 3 wähle ich ein anderes Beispiel. Es handelt sich um gewaltsames Eindringen, um ein Sich-Zugang-Verschaffen gegen den Willen der Zugangsberechtigten, wie bei einem Wohnungseinbruch. Bei einem solchen würde ich sagen:

> Die Einbrecher sind über das Dach in die darunter liegende Wohnung
>   gelangt.

Das heißt: Sie nahmen den Weg über das Dach. Dagegen:

> Die Einbrecher gelangten durch das Kellerfenster in die Wohnung.

Das heißt: Sie haben das Kellerfenster entweder aufgebrochen oder sind dort eingestiegen, weil es offen stand, sie haben sich tatsächlich durch dieses Fenster 'durch'gezwängt. Analog hieße 'durch das Dach', dass sie ein paar Dachpfannen abgedeckt hatten und durch dieses Loch ins Haus eingestiegen sind - eine aufgrund von Lärmentwicklung und Absturzrisiken nur von Anfängern in Betracht gezogene Methode.

Wenn ich den Aspekt des gewaltsamen Eindringens betonen wollte, würde ich im mittleren Beispiel 'durch' wählen; allerdings würde ich dann auch ein anderes Verb benutzen, nämlich:

> (Der Computer des Kunden ist ein Sicherheitsrisiko.) Durch ihn können
>   kriminelle Hacker sich Zugang zum Netzwerk der Bank und damit zu den
>   Kunden und zum Geld verschaffen.

Der dritte Satz erscheint mir fehlerhaft: Wenn es Kundencomputer waren, über die der Hacker eingedrungen war, dann können diese Computer nicht von der Bank gewesen sein. Es müsste vielmehr heißen:

> Als ein Hacker durch drei Kundencomputer in die Bank (besser: in das
>   interne Netzwerk der Bank) eindrang ... (mit dem **Aspekt 'gewaltsam'**)

bzw.

> Als ein Hacker über drei Kundencomputer in das interne Netzwerk der
>   Bank eindrang (mit dem **Aspekt** 'das war der **Weg**, die
>   **Zugangsmöglichkeit**').

Die Bedeutungsunterschiede sind jedoch für mich nicht stark spürbar.

Fazit: Es geht in allen drei Fällen beides, mit leichten Unterschieden bei den mitbeteiligen Nebenbedeutungen.